# Ring height stats?

Tags: astronomy, planets

I'm working on a basic simulation system which will include planets with rings, I want to create dust and asteroids within a 3D ring but I'm struggling to find any stats on the sort of height ranges a ring might have (I can find inner and outer radius estimates, but not the height ranges).

Does anybody know a good resource on planetary ring stats? Or celestial bodies in general.

Answer (score 9):

I can give you the answer for Saturn's rings because it was something I researched for a few years.  The canonical number you'll get from NASA and other sources for the height of Saturn's main rings is about 1 km.  However, actual *N*-body simulations (that I did) show that the main parts of the rings are actually significantly thinner -- sometimes only about 10-20 *meters* thick.  You'll get finer dust particles going more above and below the ring plane with larger blocks on the plane, but planetary rings in general, close to the planet, are very thin.